# Моргает экран при печатании текста

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу руби редактор, сделал раскраску текста:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentSelStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    var currentSelLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;


    richTextBox1.SelectAll();

    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;

    var matches1 = Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, @"(\bclass\b)|(\bdef\b)|(\bend\b)|("".*?"")|=begin(.+?)=end", RegexOptions.Singleline);

    foreach (var match in matches1.Cast<Match>())
    {
        richTextBox1.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
        if (match.Value[0] == '"') richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(166, 226, 46);
        else richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.FromArgb(249, 38, 114);
    }

    richTextBox1.Select(currentSelStart, currentSelLength);

    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White;
}
```

Но при печатании экран начинает моргать и текст на экране смещается так что каретка оказывается в самой верхней строке. Подозреваю, что это происходит из-за неэффективной перерисовки текста, т.е. из-за того что текст перерисовывается целиком. Скажите пожалуйста, как это можно исправить.

Comment: _"начинает моргать"_ -- потому что у вас в коде SelectAll() и сразу SelectionColor для белого цвета, потом другой цвет - ниже в цикле, и потом еще раз белый.

Comment: Последний  richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.White; лишний.

Comment: А так в целом никаких особых "морганий" и "смещений" не наблюдаю. А какой цп на той машине где вы запускаете программу? Поясню вопрос: WinForm проект для отрисовки графики использует GDI который весь обсчёт графики делает через цп. И если текст вводить быстро, а цп. слабенький или много у него другой нагрузки то начнёт подмигивать местами. У меня при очень быстром вводе больших объёмов текста (копипаст) подмигивали чуть заметно ключевые слова синим цветом выделения....

Comment: процессор - amd fx-8350, большая программа все равно сильно моргает

Comment: ну потому что текста дофига. Много отдельных операций выделения-> изменения цвета. Сама по себе операция "выделить" производит выделение аналогичное тому, что вы произведёте мышкой или операцией shift+стрелка. т.е. это не просто обозначение участка текста. И программа не знает зачем вам это выделение и честно его отрисовывает затрачивая на это ресурсы. Я тут попробовал многократный копипаст большого куска текста - подвисло знатно.

Answer (score 2):

В общем тут либо менять тип проекта на WPF (там другие механизмы изменения свойств у отдельных слов/букв в тексте у RichTextBox + отрисовка средствами GPU и к тому же оптимизируемая настройками) т.е. то же самое можно делать шустрее, без лишних ненужных выделений и в фоне.

Либо оптимизировать алгоритм. 
Сейчас по сути проблема в том, что на каждый чих (ввод 1 символа) он запускает анализ всего текста + анализ идёт в том же потоке в котором работает GUI (т.е. он блокируется)

Соответственно вам необходимо уменьшить объём анализируемого текста и максимально разгрузить управляющий GUI поток. т.е. как минимум поиск совпадений для подсветки производить в отдельном потоке. Можно в принципе и отрисовку подсветки туда же убрать, но для этого придётся отключить запрет доступа к элементам управления не из потока в котором они созданы, что потенциально может привести к неуловимым эксепшенам и прочим глюкам в будущем.

Касательно уменьшения объёмов анализируемого текста и разгрузки перерисовки: тут всё несколько сложнее. В идеале нужен алгоритм определяющий где произошли изменения и, соответственно, анализирующий и переподсвечивающий только изменяемый кусок. Алгоритм поиска изменений (сравнения двух текстов) сам по себе не тривиальный. Возможно много всяких вариантов со своими плюсами и минусами. Тут как говорится гугл вам в помощь. Но отмечу, что у вас есть информация где в данный момент находится курсор ввода. Так же вы можете отслеживать какие клавиши нажимает пользователь и т.п. Эта информация может сильно помочь в поиске места внесения изменения и их характера. Но опять же алгритм получится объёмный.

Если вы планируете что-то более серьёзное нежели подсветку отдельных символов/слов/конструкций (например анализ на предмет ошибок) то тут рано или поздно придётся реализовывать алгоритм анализа текста методом рекурсивного спуска (или что-то аналогичное) С его помощью заодно возможно будет решить и проблему поиска изменившихся мест.